# how does this python function continue even after return is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, queue, tree-traversal

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
from queue import Queue
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
        ret = []
        q = Queue()
        q.put(root)
        q.put('levelEnd')
        a = []
        
        while(not q.empty()):
            e = q.get()
            print("-e-",q.empty(), e)
            if (q.empty()) :
                print("return is called") #------------------------------------
                return(ret)
            if e == 'levelEnd':
               ret.append(a)
               a = [] 
               if (not q.empty()) : q.put('levelEnd')
            else: 
                a.append(e.val) #------------------------------------Line 27
                if (e.left != None) : q.put(e.left)
                if (e.right != None) : q.put(e.right)
```

this is the code i wrote on leetcode for problem "102. Binary Tree Level Order Traversal " and the input is [3,9,20,null,null,15]

and the output i get is :

-e- False TreeNode{val: 3, left: TreeNode{val: 9, left: None, right: None}, right: TreeNode{val: 20, left: TreeNode{val: 15, left: None, right: None}, right: None}}
-e- False levelEnd
-e- False TreeNode{val: 9, left: None, right: None}
-e- False TreeNode{val: 20, left: TreeNode{val: 15, left: None, right: None}, right: None}
-e- False levelEnd
-e- False TreeNode{val: 15, left: None, right: None}
-e- True levelEnd
return is called
-e- False TreeNode{val: 1, left: None, right: None}
-e- True levelEnd
return is called
-e- False None

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
    a.append(e.val)
Line 27 in levelOrder (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().levelOrder(param_1)
Line 52 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 63 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

How does this python function continue even after return is called?

this function should stop after return is called

Comment: Have you put a `print` as the first statement inside `levelOrder` to make sure that the method isn't just being called more than once?

Comment: from queue import Queue ?? what is this about ?

Comment: @pippo1980 What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Wondering if it is related to the:  isn't just being called more than once? - question above

Comment: @Axe319 yes i put a print and observed the function is not being called more than once